# C++ / CLI code gets slower inside loop

Tags: performance, c++-cli, stopwatch

guys

I'm writing a code in C++/CLI using Visual Studio 2015.

Right now, I'm facing an odd problem. My code runs slower as it iterates inside a loop. My code runs in a backgroundworker and it's as follows:

```
for(Int32 d = 0; d < 365; d++){
  DoStuff1();
  DoStuff2();
  DoStuff3();
  DoStuff4();
};
```

As days "d" pass by, the code runs slower, i.e., it takes more time to go from day "d" to day "d + 1".
I've tried to locate the source of the problem by using the StopWatch class 'around' each of the DoStuff methods. I did it like this:

```
timeOperations->StartNew;
DoStuff1();
timeOperations->Stop();                     
milliSec = timeOperations->ElapsedMilliseconds; 
Print(milliSec);
```

By looking at milliSec for each DoStuff method, I can see that the computation times don't change as day "d" is iterated. That is, the computation time for DoStuff1 is the same in "d = 0", "d = 1", ..., "d = 70" and so forth. The same pattern happens for the other DoStuff methods, only with different computation times.

On top of that, I also tried wrapping the stopwatch around all DoStuff methods, like this:

```
for(Int32 d = 0; d < 365; d++){
  timeOperations->StartNew;
  DoStuff1();
  DoStuff2();
  DoStuff3();
  DoStuff4();
  timeOperations->Stop();                       
  milliSec = timeOperations->ElapsedMilliseconds; 
  Print(milliSec); 
};
```

This also results in the same computation time for everyday. Despite that I can clearly see that the code goes slower and slower as day "d" is iterated.

I don't know what is happening. I hope some of you guys have solved this problem before and can give me some tips.

I appreciate any insights into how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure but shouldn't `timeOperations->StartNew` be `timeOperations->StartNew()` ? In Python, that would do nothing (function pointer, not function call) and that could explain your bug.

Comment: Hey, Jean. I've tried timeOperations->StartNew() as well and nothing changed.

Comment: forgive me for giving you false hopes :) but from the answer, it seems that I wasn't too far from the truth...

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

1. Your code is getting slower as it iterates.
2. The timing code you added is showing identical results for each iteration.

It's really hard to diagnose the first one without showing us the exact code, or at least the timing numbers so we know how much slower it's getting. But the second one we can help.

You're never restarting your stopwatch.

As you have it right now, you have one stopwatch that you create initially (somewhere in code you're not showing), you stop it, get the time, but you never start it again. That's why the stopwatch is showing identical results.

[`StartNew`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.startnew.aspx) is a static method on the Stopwatch class. You should call it statically to create and start a new stopwatch.

```
timeOperations = Stopwatch::StartNew();
```

Alternatively, you could keep the same stopwatch object, and [restart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.restart(v=vs.110).aspx) the timer.

```
timeOperations->Restart();
```

Comment: Thanks, David.

Using timeOperations->Stopwatch::Restart(); along with timeOperations->Stopwatch::StartNew(); also worked.

I would have spent some time trying to solve this on my own.

Comment: Doing both is unnecessary. Either restart your existing one or save the new one that you create, no need to do both.